# How can I execute code before DataSource.groovy is evaluated in Grails?

Tags: grails

DataSource.groovy appears to be evaluated before BootStrap.groovy. But, I need to setup something up so that I can invoke some static methods in DataSource.groovy (my database setup is complex).

More Info:

If I was doing this up without Grails, I would probably create a DataSourceFactory Spring Bean. I would then declare dependencies between this bean and other code such that I could explicitly control when everything was initialized. Within my DataSourceFactory class' PostConstruct method, I would execute the code needed to call my company's property/configuration framework to get the necessary DB connection information.

So, what I'm looking for is complete (or at least more) programatic control over how the JDBC DataSource is constructed.

Comment: What kind of code you want to evaluate? DataSource.groovy is only config file, basically it define only key=>value pairs used by other parts of grails

Comment: It would help to know a bit more about the way in which your DB setup is complex. It's possible that there is an easy way to do what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataSource.groovy` is evaluated as an executable groovy file.  Why don't you just call your methods right at the start?  For example:

```
MyApp.doExtraDatabaseConfig()

dataSource {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That might do the trick. I'm a little worried that would get messy having part of my Bootstrap code called from the DataSource file directly, but maybe that's my only choice.